# Variable Undefined in Javascript after Explicit Assignment?

Tags: javascript, variables, closures

For some reason my "initialLocation" variable is undefined when I make an alert on it, even though I explicitly assign it in the callback function for getCurrentPosition.
Variable "initialLocation" is declared globally btw.

Maybe I'm not understanding this concept of closures?

```
var initialLocation;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    geoLocationError = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        getFood();
        }, geoError);
    alert(initialLocation);
} else {
    geoLocationError = false;
    noGeolocation(geoLocationError);
}
```

Comment: can you copy and paste the error in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: geolocation is asynchronous....you are trying to alert the value before it has been returned from location service

Comment: Also, [use `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).

Comment: Place the `alert` inside `getCurrentPosition`

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so your alert is firing before `initialLocation` is set. You should place your alert inside the callback, just after you set `initialLocation`.